# Robot Framework - Drag and Drop not working

Tags: robotframework

A Drag & Drop operation is not working for me.  The Id defns and operation statement is given below.  The test case passes, however, drag and drop functionality is not happenings... The element is where it was

Request for help.....Is it that element id is not correct?

${**DragFromPlaceId**}              xpath:/html/body/app-root/div/app-master/div/div[3]/div/div/div/app-campaign-builder/div/div/div/app-build-audience/article/section/app-dynamic-variable-mapping/article/footer/section[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6R85.png)/div/div/span[4]

${**DropToPlaceId**}                xpath:/html/body/app-root/div/app-master/div/div[3]/div/div/div/app-campaign-builder/div/div/div/app-build-audience/article/section/app-dynamic-variable-mapping/article/footer/section[2]/div/ul/li[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6R85.png)/h5

drag and drop       ${DragFromPlaceId}      ${DropToPlaceId}

[image]

Comment: Depending on the how the site has been implemented, default selenium "drag and drop" functionality wont work for all implementation types. As with your file upload issue, SeleniumTestability adds extra argument "html5" that works around this issue. github.com/marketSquare/robotframework-seleniumtestability

Comment: Can you pls help me in this ...

Comment: 1) Did you install robotframework-seleniumtestability ? and 2) pass html5=True to `Drag and Drop` keyword besides the normal locators .. @user2609370

Comment: Yes through PIP.

*command*
python -m robot  -
 SeleniumLibrary::plugins=SeleniumTestability  .\MBM\MOC.robot


error
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'SeleniumLibrary::plugins=SeleniumTestability' failed: File 
or directory to execute does not exist.

code 
Drag And Drop        ${DragFromPlaceId}  ${DropToPlaceId}   html5=True

output
Keyword 'SeleniumLibrary.Drag And Drop' expected 2 arguments, got 3

change  done- 
seleniumtestability.Drag And Drop        ${DragFromPlaceId}  ${DropToPlaceId}   html5=True

result  - No keyword with name 'seleniumtestability.Drag And Drop' found.

Comment: https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-seleniumtestability has installation instructions and fully working examples under atest/ directory. Also SeleniumTestability is a addon/plugin to SeleniumLibrary, not a separate keyword library so once you have installed it, and added the correct argument to  `Library   SeleniumLibrary`, all the new keywords are available directly from SeleniumLibrary.

Comment: aka, read the  README first which is fully visible when you go the the github repo.

Comment: Is it possible for us to catch up offline.....It will help me

Comment: I've added  under Settings-
Library         SeleniumLibrary         plugins=SeleniumTestability;True;30 Seconds;True


When I run the test case, I get the below error


Error in file 'D:\Kiushore-OFF\MBMP\MBMPFEAutomation\RobotProcedures\MbmpProcedures.robot' on line 2: Initializing library 'SeleniumLibrary' with arguments [ plugins=SeleniumTestability;True;30 Seconds;True ] failed: Importing test library 'SeleniumTestability' failed: AttributeError: type object 'DesiredCapabilities' has no attribute 'OPERA'

Comment: when is the release expected for this issue

Comment: When is the SeleniumTestability release happening.... Im eagerly waiting for the same

Answer (score 0):

Please check draggable attribute value. if the attribute value false we unable to perform drag and drop. draggable attribute value should be true then only we can able to perform drag and drop function in automation.